"Angular HttpClient data inconsistency after page refresh: duplicate or missing entries in list"
I'm working on an Angular project where I display a list of tables at the top of the page. When I click on a table name, I use Angular's HttpClient and ActivatedRoute to fetch the selected table's details based on the id parameter in the route. However, after refreshing the page, the list of table names at the top sometimes loads inconsistently: sometimes it shows duplicates, sometimes all entries are missing, and sometimes it loads correctly.
Loaded table name twice, (after refresh)
No Table name
My Service class:
getTables(): Observable<Table[]> {
    return this._http.get<Table[]>(`${this.apiUrl}/GetTableDescriptors`)
    .pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        console.error(this.handleError(error));
        return throwError(() => new Error('Error geting tables!'));
      })
    );
  };

getCurrentTable(_tableID: string): Observable<Table> {
    return this._http.get<Table>(`${this.apiUrl}/Table/${_tableID}`)
    .pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        console.error(this.handleError(error));
        return throwError(() => new Error("Error getting table with an id {_tableID}"));
      })
    );
  };

App Routes ts file:
export const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: 'table/:id', component: TableComponent},
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];


@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

App component:
  <app-page-header></app-page-header>

Page Header Component:
export class PageHeaderComponent implements OnInit{
  tables: Table[] = [];

  constructor(
              private _tableService: TableService) { }
              
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTables();
  }
  
  getTables() {
    this.tables = [];
    this._tableService.getTables().subscribe((_tablesFromAPI: Table[]) => {
      this.tables = _tablesFromAPI; 
    });
  }
}


<ul>
    <li>
        <a routerLink="/home" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">Start</a>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let table of tables; let i = index">
            <a
                [routerLink]="'/table/' + table.id"
                [routerLinkActive]="['active']"
                >
                {{table.name}}
            </a>
        </ng-container>
    </li>
</ul>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

Table Component:
  export class TableComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

    currentTable: Table;
    
    constructor(private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.paramMapSubscription = this._activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe((_activateRoute: ParamMap) => {
        this.tableIndex = _activateRoute.get('id');
        try {
          this._tableService.getCurrentTable(this.tableIndex).subscribe( {
          next: (_tableFromServer: Table) => {
            this.currentTable = _tableFromServer;
          },
          error: err => console.log('error: ',err)
        })
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        }
      });
    }
    
    ngOnDestroy(): void {
      if (this.paramMapSubscription) {
        this.paramMapSubscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    }
  }

I have tried:

Using the async pipe in the template to manage subscriptions.
Checking for potential redundant subscriptions or lifecycle issues.

How can I ensure that the table names are loaded consistently without duplicates or missing entries after a page refresh? Is there a better approach to managing data caching and navigation state in this setup? Thanks 

the code seems fine at a glance, could you check the network tab of chrome inspector if the API calls return the data properly

@NarenMurali, Thanks for the suggestion! I checked the Network tab, and the API calls return the correct data consistently, matching the database. Even using Swagger or Postman, the data is accurate.
One more thing: The "Start" tab is hardcoded in the Angular component. Refreshing while being on the "Start" tab displays everything correctly, but refreshing while being on a route parameter of the table (e.g., viewing table itself) causes the data inconsistency.

if you share a stackblitz or a github repo where the issue happens, it would be great for debugging

@NarenMurali, Thanks for your help! Unfortunately, I’m unable to share a StackBlitz or GitHub repo due to data privacy restrictions. However, I’ve created a minimal reproduction of the issue using mock data, but the error doesn’t appear in this version. I’ll compare the two implementations to identify the differences. Thank you for your understanding! , and I’ll reach out again once I have more information!

sometimes the server-side-rendering part of angular can act twice on the some object if the reference is the same. Meaning that the server made a request, it gets cached with whatever operation hapenned after. When the client side gets rendered, the operation gets duplicated. Check if you are not doing any operations on the returning object from the api call
